# This error has occured in magento 2, how can I fix it?

Tags: magento2

> Warning: include(/home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on line 326

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following commands in the given order and check,

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

rm -rf var/{cache,di,generation,page_cache,view_preprocessed}

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `dev/template/minify_html` is enabled and if it is, disable it.

You can check this in the admin under **Stores -> Configuration -> Advance -> Developer -> Template Settings** or in the `core_config_table` filtering by the path `dev/template/minify_html`.

If disabling this fixes the issue, it is very likely that there is something wrong in your custom theme.

I would carry on debugging, perhaps switch the theme to luma or blank and see if they work with `minify_html` enabled, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `var` folder content by below command,

```
rm -rf var/generation/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/_requirejs/ var/cache var/di var/page_cache pub/static/_cache
```

Now, give full permission to the `var` folder,

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/
```

> If the above method is not working then check your file and folder
> permissions, You need to give permissions to your Magento 2 instance. Check [Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html) for file permissions

**Hope it helps.**