# My website is not working, I am having this error

Tags: magento2

> Warning:
> include(/home/occ_vikas/occasionsjo.com/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/occ_vikas/occasionsjo.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php
> on line 327

Comment: Check with developer mode, Is it working or not.
If not execute composer update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This error has occured in magento 2, how can I fix it?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285362/this-error-has-occured-in-magento-2-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: I provided a potential fix for this issue [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371007/4659)

Answer (score 0):

Simply deploy through CMD

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

it will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -Rf var/view_proccessed
rm -Rf var/cache
rm -Rf pub/static/frontend    
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

If it not works, tell us if all of madantory Magento 2 packages are installed.

And what's your Magento version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below commands:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

rm -Rf var/view_proccessed
rm -Rf var/cache
rm -Rf pub/static/frontend
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f or php bin/magento cache:flush

Try to check if you work on some custom module, and add a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all suggestions try also doing:

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please run the below command first to remove var folder.

   **rm -rf var/page_cache var/cache var/composer_home var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed**
2. Rename **composer.lock** to **composer.lock.bk** file from root.
3. After that run below commands one by one.

   **composer install**

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**
   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
   **php bin/magento cache:flush**